# SameSite=None w/ Secure Breaking iFrame in IE11

Tags: asp.net, cookies, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, samesite

With the recent changes it seems that SameSite cookie attributes are throwing a wrench into my website now. A cross-browser iframe that was working before on my site is now broken - even with the SameSite=None; Secure being passed through the iFrame in the response header.

I've seen very different reports from people saying Windows 7 doesn't support SameSite=none. Others saying the Secure is breaking or not breaking it. But even the current Microsoft documentation doesn't lay out exactly how Win7 IE11 should react to SameSite=None.

At this point I'm looking for some tips or tricks from anyone who could assist. I've done everything I can think of. This worked before and now suddenly is blocking out the iFrame and throwing a 500 error. Could the order of the set-cookie be causing this?

From some browser testing I've found the following:

Windows 10   - IE11 broken, Edge broken, Edge(beta) **works**

Windows 8.1  - IE11 **works**, Edge(beta) **works**

Windows 8    - IE11 broken, Edge(beta) **works**

Windows 7    - IE11 broken, No Edge

The Set-Cookie response header:
`Set-Cookie   MySitePersistence=436457226.47873.0000; path=/; httponly; secure; SameSite=none; Secure`

I tried targeting IE directly as a rewrite preCondition using
`<add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />`
`<add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=none" negate="true" />`
`<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\\.0-9]{0,})*.*$" negate="true" />`
`<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^.*Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\\.0-9]{0,})*.*$" negate="true" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because Asp.NET_SessionID cookie was not being sent always due to new changes in cookies and the cookie now had a **SameSite=Lax** attribute.

You could set the SameSite property for the session cookie to **“None”** by adding this in **web.config**:

```
<system.web>     
     <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />     
</system.web>
```

This with the outbound rules **(SameSite=None; Secure)** will work. You could refer to [this simiar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076007/internet-explorer-edge-not-chromium-add-additional-samesite-lax-when-samesite).

*More information to reference:*

(1) [SameSite in code for your ASP.net applications](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/samesite-in-code-for-your-asp-net-applications/ba-p/1156361)

(2) [SameSite=Lax in the new world](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/samesite-lax-in-the-new-world/ba-p/1156292)

(3) [SameSite cookie updates in ASP.net, or how the .Net Framework from December changed my cookie usage](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/samesite-cookie-updates-in-asp-net-or-how-the-net-framework-from/ba-p/1156246)

Comment: Updating <sessionState> to include cookieSameSite="None" is what fixed it. The only worry I have is this would be adding sameSite="none" to every page correct? Before we were trying to target only particular browsers. What type of security issues should we be worried about now?